# How can we compare arules with other methods in recommenderlab package for R

Tags: r, arules

I am trying to compare algorithms for recommendation using package recommenderlab in R. Just want to know how can I incorporate association rules in list of algorithms for comparison (Can results from arules package be used)

```
algorithms <- list(
"random items" = list(name="RANDOM", param=list(normalize = "Z-score")),
"popular items" = list(name="POPULAR", param=list(normalize = "Z-score")),
"user-based CF" = list(name="UBCF", param=list(normalize = "Z-score",
                                             method="Cosine",
                                             nn=50, minRating=3)))
```

**# want to add "Assoc-Rules" = "arules etc."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a binaryRatingMatrix you can use AR.
You can get the entries you can use with "binaryRatingMatrix" with following code:

```
recommenderRegistry$get_entries(dataType = "binaryRatingMatrix")
```

It will indicate the method and the parameters you can use.